# How do I get winston-cloudwatch via aws lambda to work?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, winston

The following code works as expected, logging the two messages to **Log groups
/aws/lambda/50-calculate-market-cap > stream-FN50** (which it creates) when run from cmd line using;
**node local.js** (not its actual name!)
aws credentials DO NOT match program, but as it works I assume that the program credentials override aws configure?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var winston = require('winston');
const WinstonCloudWatch = require('winston-cloudwatch');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new WinstonCloudWatch({
      logGroupName: 'log-group-T03',
      logStreamName: 'stream-T03b',
      awsAccessKeyId: "********************",
      awsSecretKey: "****************************************",
      awsRegion: 'us-east-1',
      jsonMessage: true
    })
  ]
});

var d1 = new Date().toISOString();

logger.error('II am done w/ error '+d1);
logger.info('II am done w/ info '+d1);
```

So when I use this code lambda.js ;)

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const winston = require('winston');
const WinstonCloudWatch = require('winston-cloudwatch');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new WinstonCloudWatch({
      logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/FN50',
      logStreamName: 'stream-FN50',
      awsAccessKeyId: "********************",
      awsSecretKey: "****************************************",
      awsRegion: 'us-east-1',
      jsonMessage: true
    })
  ]
});

// Code to handle SNS event 
exports.handler =  async (event) => {
    var d1 = new Date().toISOString();

    logger.info('WinstonCloudWatch - logging '+d1);
    console.log('Console - logging '+d1);

    try {
        for (var record of event.Records) {
            const SNSmessage = JSON.parse(record.Sns.Message);
            console.log('SNSmessage: ', SNSmessage);
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
    return true;
};
```

I would expect it to work!

Lambda fn is deployed as follows;

```
**aws lambda update-function-code --function-name ${npm_package_SNS_fn} --zip-file fileb://${npm_package_SNS_srcZip}**
```

```
"Role": "arn:aws:iam::************:role/lambda-sns-role",
```

```
aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name lambda-sns-role
```

```
{
    "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "CloudWatchFullAccess",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchFullAccess"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

The program is run as follows;

```
> aws sns publish --message file://message.txt --subject TestTrade --topic-arn 
${npm_package_SNS_srcARN}

{
    "MessageId": "64dafc32-6fd3-50fc-8073-a5ea47f56233"
}
```

The console.log output is returned as per the original program, but **NO log-groups, streams or logger output is produced**, any help is appreciated?

Comment: I found this post [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58030325/winston-cloudwatch-transport-not-creating-logs-when-running-on-lambda ) which seems almost identical to what I'm experiencing, BUT i've discounted it on the basis that I'm using a Lambda function subscribed to SNS, any views?

Comment: So, since posting this I've tried various things including; 1) trying to terminate and flush the transport using 'kthxbye' but I couldn't get this to work (?) @lazywithclass 2) I added a timer to await 3secs and this WORKED! But NOT sure this is suitable for AWS Lambda!

Comment: Lots of discussion about winston use in AWS lambda here, there seems to be an issue with the lambda freezing before it can get the logs out. https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1250